# Pandas data frame where each row is a list where blank space needs to be replaced with a comma

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I have a pandas data frame read from a **.csv** file where the output is something like this:

```
1     [44 48 50 55 56 57]
2     [49 54 57 61 62 64]
3     [45 51 53 58 59 61]
4     [47 52 54 59 60 62]
```

Each row is to be the list for a separate for loop.

I need each value in the lists to be delimited with a comma.

I've tried using **df.replace (' ', ',')**, this returns the same lists.

Below is the code I'm using to produce the data frame:

```
dfm2 = pd.read_csv ('/Users/uni/Desktop/corrindex+id/res_rt512_58_60_71_76_79_81.txt', sep = ',', delimiter = ',', usecols = [18], index_col = False, header=None)

print dfm2
```

Any insight on how to get each list delimited by a comma would be appreciated.

Comment: You are missing inplace=True parameter in replace function.

Check out the documentation to see how inplace changes the output.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: Thanks. I tried this : ```rp = df.replace('  ', ',', inplace = True)

print rp ``` but when printed I receive 'none'. I'm trying to replace the blank space between each value i'm unsure if this is possible with pandas .replace

Comment: Use either,
df.replace(' ', ',', inplace = True) 
OR
rp = df.replace(' ', ',') 

Do read the documentation in the link to see how inplace works.

Answer (score 0):

Since each value is a string, and you're dealing with a `pd.Series` object more than a `pd.DataFrame` object, you should use `pd.Series.str.replace` (use the `squeeze` parameter in the pd.read_csv function to force the csv as a `pd.Series` on read)